# Which layer I should implement caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, caching

My website is going. However, having many clients to call to server to get data which will connect to database to retrieve. To improve database's performance, I need to implement cache in web server.

I should implement it in Data Access or Model layer. I'm using ASP.NET MVC. Thanks.

Comment: How is your data access layer implemented? Is it an ORM or is it hand-coded?

Comment: What are you caching? How frequently is it requested? How many variations of it are there? How big is it? How many concurrent users? How long can you stand "stale" data? Why do you want to cache in you data access layer?

Comment: Start by caching entire controller methods where it makes sense..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be 2 levels of caching in a web application:

1. Caching entire actions or fragments of HTML
2. Caching result objects from data access operations

The first scenario is achieved by decorating actions/child actions with the [`[OutputCache]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx) attribute.

The second is more fine grained and it will depend on your setup. For example if you are using an ORM such as NHibernate, maybe your ORM already supports caching. For example NHibernate supports second level cache which could even be externalized using caching providers. So if you are using an ORM head towards the documentation of your ORM to see whether it supports such caching functionality.

If your ORM doesn't support caching or you are not using an ORM at all then you could build caching yourself. This could be achieved at your Service Layer where you could inject some cache provider as dependency and when your service queries your repositories, cache the results returned by those repositories using the provider.